# Has a wingsuit pilot ever flown inverted for an extended period of time (say more than 5 seconds)?

Tags: skydiving

Has a wingsuit pilot ever flown inverted for an extended period of time (say more than 5 seconds)?

(Additional content added to add length to "meet our quality standards") --

It seems it should be possible.  But perhaps it would be too disorienting.  Or perhaps the suit is made to curve in a certain way that is not compatible with sustained inverted flight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Red Bull (who else?) did it: [*Umgedrehter Wingsuit-Flug über die Dolomiten* (inverted wingsuit flight over the dolomites)](https://redbull.com/de-de/umgedrehter-wingsuit-flug-%C3%BCber-die-dolomiten?rbup-media-time=39&rbup-media-id=rrn%3Acontent%3Avideos%3A77fda5d4-14cb-42cc-a0c8-4ae92ec27760%3Aen-INT).

[image: Umgedrehter Wingsuit-Flug über die Dolomiten (inverted wingsuit flight over the dolomites)]

It looks to be around 10 seconds. Parts of the video are in slow-motion, but this part does look real-time.

Comment: It's working much weaker muscles across the back and triceps. It doesn't look like he can hold it more than maybe 10 or 15 sec.

Comment: Not just the muscles, even relaxing the chest the arms only go so far back falling/gliding face down.  (you can't easily clap your hands behind your back!)  While backwards the full force of the air would be trying to push your arms together in front of you...